# How to modify library in makefile

Tags: c++, makefile

I have a makefile that I need to modify to include the path to libraries.I am trying to run program given to me by someone else. I'm really confused on how the makefile works and don't understand what the previous lines are.

These are the directions given to me to modify the makefile:

Change the lines:
    INCS = -I"../../LIB/libpca/include"

```
LIBS = -L"../../LIB/libpca/build" -lpca -larmadillo

in the Makefile to represent the folder where you installed the libpca and armadillo libraries.
```

Now I now what my new paths are:

Desktop/PCA-CD/Libraries

but I don't understand what is is that I really need to change.

Here is what the makefile looks like:

```
PROG = CD

UNAME := $(shell uname)

ifeq ($(UNAME), Darwin)
CXX = clang++ -stdlib=libc++
else
CXX = g++
endif

FLAGS = -O0 -g3 -Wall -std=c++0x -pthread

INCS = -I"../../LIB/libpca/include" 

LIBS = -L"../../LIB/libpca/build" -lpca -larmadillo

SRCS = CD.cpp

RM = rm -f

all :
    $(CXX) $(FLAGS) $(INCS) $(SRCS) $(LIBS) -o $(PROG)
    # $(CXX) $(FLAGS)  $(SRCS)  -o $(PROG)

clean :
    $(RM) $(PROG)
```

Thanks for any help provided.

Answer (score 0):

I think they're suggesting to change the line:

```
INCS = -I"../../LIB/libpca/include" 
LIBS = -L"../../LIB/libpca/build" -lpca -larmadillo
```

to

```
INCS = -I"Desktop/PCA-CD/Libraries/include"
LIBS = -L"Desktop/PCA-CD/Libraries/build" -lpca -larmadillo
```

Notice that `Desktop/PCA-CD/Libraries` is a relative path, and assumes that the library is stored in the subdirectory of the build directory.  From your build directory, try running `ls Desktop/PCA-CD/Libraries/build`, to confirm it is right path.  If it's not, replace it with the absolute path of the directory where you installed the library.